# Bulk operations in CassandraRepository for spring-data-cassandra 2.0M1

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-cassandra

I have a simple spring-data-cassandra project that tries to insert multiple entities using

```
<S extends T> Iterable<S> save(Iterable<S> entities)
```

of the `CassandraRepository` class.

However when I use version `2.0.0.M1` (works in previous versions), I get the following error,

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.VerifierMappingExceptions: java.util.ArrayList:
- Cassandra entities must be annotated with either @Persistent, @Table, @UserDefinedType or @PrimaryKeyClass

at org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.CompositeCassandraPersistentEntityMetadataVerifier$PersistentAnnotationVerifier.verify(CompositeCassandraPersistentEntityMetadataVerifier.java:92)
at org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.CompositeCassandraPersistentEntityMetadataVerifier.verify(CompositeCassandraPersistentEntityMetadataVerifier.java:70)
at org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.BasicCassandraPersistentEntity.verify(BasicCassandraPersistentEntity.java:160)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:332)
at org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.BasicCassandraMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(BasicCassandraMappingContext.java:381)
at org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.BasicCassandraMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(BasicCassandraMappingContext.java:65)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:185)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:145)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:70)
at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate.getPersistentEntity(CassandraTemplate.java:427)
at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate.getTableName(CassandraTemplate.java:443)
at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate.insert(CassandraTemplate.java:314)
at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate.insert(CassandraTemplate.java:302)
at org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.support.SimpleCassandraRepository.save(SimpleCassandraRepository.java:66)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:553)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:538)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:479)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:460)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy34.save(Unknown Source)
```

My main class, `App.java`

```
public class App
{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext context =new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(CassandraConfig.class);
    CustomerRepo repo=context.getBean(CustomerRepo.class);
    List<Customer> customers=new ArrayList<Customer>();

    Customer cust=new Customer();
    cust.SetId("142");
    cust.setName("Mayor");
    cust.setAcc_type("new");
    cust.setAcc_name("savings");
    cust.setSegment("Normal");
    customers.add(cust);

    Customer cust1 = new Customer();
    cust1.SetId("143");
    cust1.setName("Final");
    cust1.setAcc_type("new");
    cust1.setAcc_name("savings");
    cust1.setSegment("Normal");
    customers.add(cust1);

    repo.save(customers);

   }
}
```

The entity class, `Customer.java`

```
@Table(value="Customer")
public class Customer {

 @PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "id",ordinal = 1,type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
 private String id;
 @Column(value ="name")
 private String name;
 @Column(value = "acc_name")
 private String acc_name;
 @Column(value = "acc_type")
 private String acc_type;
 @Column(value = "segment")
 private String segment;



 public Customer(String id, String name, String acc_name, String acc_type,
        String segment) {

     this.id=id;
     this.name=name;
     this.acc_name=acc_name;
     this.acc_type=acc_type;
     this.segment=segment;

}


public Customer() {

}


public void SetId(String id)
 {
     this.id=id;
 }


 public void setName(String name)
 {
     this.name=name;
 }


 public void setAcc_name(String acc_name)
 {
     this.acc_name=acc_name;
 }

 public void setAcc_type(String acc_type)
 {
     this.acc_type=acc_type;

 }

 public void setSegment(String segment)
 {
     this.segment=segment;

 }

 public String getId() {
  return id;
 }


 public String getName() {
  return name;
 }

 public String getAcc_name() {
  return acc_name;
 }

 public String getAcc_type() {
      return acc_type;
}

 public String getSegment() {
      return segment;
}


}
```

And finally, the repository, `CustomerRepo.java`

```
import com.Entity.Customer;
public interface CustomerRepo extends CassandraRepository<Customer> {

}
```

Is this an issue (I haven't been able to find via Goolge or the site), or am I missing some annotations ?

Comment: That's a bug. I filed a ticket: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACASS-396. Save each element by iterating the array.

Comment: @mp911de Ah, ok. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

For batch queries, use CassandraTemplate helps to insert batch of operations with multiple entities. This is available with  Spring Data Cassandra.

example code:

```
CassandraBatchOperations batchOps = cassandraTemplate.batchOps();  
batchOps(movieByGenre);  
batchOps(movieByActor);  
batchOps.insert(movie);  
batchOps.execute();
```

This will use Cassandra native Batch operation internally.